# Mongoose find objects with the same String values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am looking for a solution which checks if an object with the same combination of strings already exists in the database. If so I don't want to create a new db entry. I thought about generation a hash out of the 3 strings, but maybe there is a better solution. Is it possible to check of an object with the same values exists in the database (every object has this `_id`, which makes this probably impossible?)

Following the model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var keywordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    basis: String,
    buchstabe: String,
    ergebnis: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Keyword', keywordSchema);
```

And thats the part I use to save into the database:

```
obj = {
    basis: basiswort,
    buchstabe: buchstabe,
    ergebnis: ergebnis
};
var neuesKeyword = new Keyword(obj);
//Check if the a combination already exists
neuesKeyword.save();
```

before  adding a new database entry it should check is there an entry "basis" in the database that equals the new value AND is there an entry "buchstabe" in the database that equals the new value AND is there an entry "ergebnis" in the database that equals the new value. only if all 3 checks are true and all 3 string exist whithin one database object i dont want to save the new object to the database.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Answer (score 0):

basis: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }}

Comment: ok, but all 3 String basis buchstabe and ergebnis should be checked. before  adding a new database entry it should check is there an entry "basis" in the database that equals the new value AND is there an entry "buchstabe" in the database that equals the new value AND is there an entry "ergebnis" in the database that equals the new value. only if all 3 checks are true and all 3 string exist whithin one database object i dont want to save the new object to the database.